# why does box-shadow disappear for a div when i remove the relative position for the div?

Tags: css

i have a top_div which when set to relative position box shadow retains. and when i remove relative position box shadow disappears. could someone help me understanding this or where am i going wrong.

Below is the code,

```
<div class="top_div">
    <div class="drawer">
        <div class="menu">
            <header>
                <Svg>
                <button></button>
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul></div></div></div>


.top_div {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    align-items: center;
 }
.drawer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: $white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 380px;
    top: 55px;
    right: 8px;
    min-height: 40%;
    max-height: 80%;

    header {
        height: 41px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-top: 2px;

        svg {
            margin-left: 16px; 
        }
    }

    ul {
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }}}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, maybe your browser has difficulties rendering your HTML. There's a loose SVG tag doing absolutely nothing unclosed in your <header> which could be the root of the problem. Also, nesting inside CSS Rules is not possible. E.G `header { svg { margin-left: 16px; } }` is not possible.

Based on your current code, you're definitely going way to fast. Try to start from the basics, have a goal. Take a design from internet or build one yourself and try to reproduce that in code.

Comment: if you can create a jsffidle or a wroking example or add the full code so we can test it